# Adding a header to a web API request in the data sources section of a report in PBI Report Server

Tags: powerbi, http-headers, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have created a report using power bi desktop (Version January 2021). In order to get the data for this report, I connect to a web API using the provided API key in the header part of the request:

[image]

This part works fine and I get the necessary data to work on the Power BI desktop.

When I publish the created report to a Power BI Report Server, as you can see in the following image, there is no way to add the header data which in this case is mandatory to authenticate:

[image]

The Authentication part in the Credential section in the above image does not support adding headers data and only accepts Anonymous, Basic, and Windows authentication which are not applicable here (The test fails).

As the data in my report changes regularly and I need to schedule an automatic refresh, the Report Server has to connect to the Web API at the scheduled times in order to get the latest version of the data.

I would appreciate it if you could help me to solve the encountered problem. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The access key should be part of the query options and in PowerQuery you should have something like

```
Source = Csv.Document(
    Web.Contents(
        "http://example.com",
        [
            RelativePath = "api",
            Query = 
            [   
                api-key = "s4fad456df"
            ]
        ]
    ),
),
```

The authentication to the web data source is always Anonymous in Power BI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents